# Linux claiming android (arm-eabi-gcc) is not present when it is clearly there

Tags: linux, android-ndk

So I just trying to build a library using the NDK.  I believe that the Android.mk and Application.mk files are correct, but whether they are or not is irrelevant.

when executing `make APP=hello` within the NDK directory

> Android NDK: Building for application 'hello'
>   make: ./build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
>   Compile thumb  : hello <= apps/ssa/project/jni/hello/*.c
>   /bin/sh: ./build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: not found
>   make: *** [out/apps/ssa/armeabi/objs/hello/hello/*.o] Error 127

So from here I decided to go look and see where the file was.

`cd build/prebuild/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/`

The output of `ls -l` clearly shows the file to exist:

```
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bpescato bpescato  238680 2010-05-03 18:24 arm-eabi-g++
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bpescato bpescato  234520 2010-08-20 09:27 arm-eabi-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bpescato bpescato  234520 2010-05-03 18:24 arm-eabi-gcc-4.4.0
...
```

So I next try to simply execute it and allow it tell me the usage:

> $ ./arm-eabi-gcc
>
> bash: ./arm-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory

Then, just to make sure I'm not crazy:

> $ less arm-eabi-gcc
>
> "arm-eabi-gcc" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?

Sure enough, viewing the file displays a whole lot of binary data which is clearly present and on disk.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you fadden for the response, however it turns out that my issue was related to the fact that my VM was (unbeknownst to me) a 64 bit machine, and I was trying to run a 32 bit executable.

So, to fix the problem and keep the machine intact I would need to have followed the 64 bit instructions.

Since many of the forums reference 32 bit android ndk help, I decided to just get a new 32 bit VM.

Comment: I encountered this and managed to fix it by using 'aptitude install is32-libs' followed by 'apt-get install libc6-dev-i386'

Comment: @Andres: i assume you meant ia32-libs, that worked for me, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The file has different permissions and modification time from the two neighboring files, which makes me wonder if something mangled it a bit.  (Try "cmp arm-eabi-gcc arm-eabi-gcc-4.4.0", should be the same.)

Does "ldd arm-eabi-gcc" report any missing libraries?  What I'm thinking is that the file that is missing isn't "arm-eabi-gcc" itself, but rather something upon which it depends.

Next step would be "strace ./arm-eabi-gcc" to see what system calls it's making.